# Tabula does not detect some tables with pdfs built with the same software

Tags: python, pdftotext, tabula

I´m trying to automate the sorting of my expenses in the report of the credit card that my bank provides.

I found tabula which worked like a miracle in many pdfs making it really easy to convert to csv and then process it as I want, with just two lines of code:
https://tabula-py.readthedocs.io/en/latest/tabula.html#high-level-interfaces

```
    from tabula import convert_into_by_batch

    convert_into_by_batch('movements', output_format='csv', pages='all')
```

But i´m having troubles because in some pdfs I do not obtain results at all and it does not look logical to me. Because:

1. The pdfs apparently look the same. For obvious reasons I can not show the original file, but I can share two blurred screenshots where you can see that the files are almost identical. The one from february is detected perfectly by tabula but the other one is not:
   [image: not working photo]
   [image: working photo]
2. I don´t have access to how those pdfs are generated but I would guess that they always follow the same procedure. As this is not something that happens in new pdfs or old pdfs, just randomly in others in between.

Is there anything I can do to change how tabula detects the tables to make it more accuarate?

Answer (score 0):

Well I give an answer to myself how I worked around the issue, although is not a clean solution and I still don´t understand why tabula fails randomly in some pdfs.

I changed the method of batch to process them one by one given the area parameter.
I used foxit reader to get approximately the pixels where the table is located, which lucky in my case is always the same:
[image]

And then I wrote the code like this:

```
from tabula import convert_into
import os
import re
import sys 

directory=sys.argv[0]
output=sys.argv[1]
files = [f for f in os.listdir(directory) if re.match(r'.+\.pdf', f)]
for file in files:
    print(os.path.join(directory, file))
    convert_into(os.path.join(directory, file), output_path=os.path.join(output, file.replace(".pdf",".csv" )), pages='all', area=[[409,39,750,590]])
```

I still have to do some more testing but seems quiet robust for my scenario, although quiet ugly I would be open to see another solution which does not require this measuring system.